# Insert date from cell into sql table - Defaults to 1900-01-01

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I can update an SQL table via Excel VBA except the date. The value comes through as 1900-01-01 or in some cases where I have played with the format it is shown as 1900-01-28.

It is a simple setup just for testing.
One Table with two columns CellText and CellDate, both getting their values from a cell range.

The value expected for CellText is 'Some Text'
The value expected for CellDate is 24/03/2015

```vb
Sub UpdateTable()

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim uSQL As String
Dim strText As String
Dim strDate As Date

strText = ActiveSheet.Range("b4").Value
strDate = Format(ActiveSheet.Range("c4").Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")

Set cnn = New Connection
cnnstr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; " & _
            "Data Source=ServerName; " & _
            "Initial Catalog=DbName;" & _
            "User ID=UserName;" & _
            "Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

cnn.Open cnnstr

uSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_ExcelUpdate (CellText,CellDate) VALUES ('" & strText & "', " & strDate & ")"

Debug.Print uSQL

cnn.Execute uSQL
cnn.Close
Set cnn = Nothing
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

My Debug value is

> INSERT INTO tbl_ExcelUpdate (CellText,CellDate) VALUES ('Some Text ', 24/03/2015)

My CellDate format in table is datetime.

Comment: I don't know enough about SQL Server to provide an answer but what it looks like it going on is you're sending a number with division e.g. 24 / 3 / 2015 = 0.004.  I bet when you get 1900-01-28 the date is going in like 2015 / 3 / 24 = ~28.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing single quotes on either side of the date.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_ExcelUpdate (CellText,CellDate) VALUES ('Some Text ', 24/03/2015)
```

Should be

```
INSERT INTO tbl_ExcelUpdate (CellText,CellDate) VALUES ('Some Text ', '24/03/2015')
```

Comment: Thanks @Dbloch but if I try put the date in single quotes I get a conversion error Char to DateTime as SQL destination is a DateTime and stick the single quotes on will convert it to a string.

Comment: Temporarily change the "datetime" column to a nvarchar(100) and try it and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks @Dbloch this works fine and I think for now I will use this method as I I will be creating a view from the SQL table so I can convert back to date there.

Answer (score 0):

Use CDate function to convert string formated date to date type

```
Sub UpdateTable()

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim uSQL As String
Dim strText As String
Dim strDate As Date

strText = ActiveSheet.Range("b4").Value
strDate = Format(ActiveSheet.Range("c4").Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")

Set cnn = New Connection
cnnstr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; " & _
        "Data Source=ServerName; " & _
        "Initial Catalog=DbName;" & _
        "User ID=UserName;" & _
        "Trusted_Connection=Yes;"


cnn.Open cnnstr     uSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_ExcelUpdate (CellText,CellDate) VALUES ('" & strText & "', " & CDate(strDate) & ")"

Debug.Print uSQL

cnn.Execute uSQL
cnn.Close
Set cnn = Nothing
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @rajnikant I have tried this but the result is the same.

Comment: I haev followed lots of other forum threads and had no success. Not sure what exactly it is I have done wrong.

Comment: you have CellDate format in table is datetime but you are sending only date, thats why it is not working

Answer (score 0):

you have to correct the `strDate = Format(ActiveSheet.Range("c4").Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")` to

```
strDate = Format(ActiveSheet.Range("c4").Value, "dd-mm-yyyy").
```

Then you have to put quotes:

```
uSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_ExcelUpdate (CellText,CellDate) VALUES ('" & strText & "', '" & strDate & "')"
```